# Creating Clock in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, date, timer

I have a website and I want to put a realtime clock on one of the pages.
I have written the code using hooks but I understand using hooks for such cases is bad for performance due to rerenders in states every second.
Is there a less resource intensive solution?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Footer() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    setInterval(() => {

      const dateObject = new Date()

      const hour = dateObject.getHours()
      const minute = dateObject.getMinutes()
      const second = dateObject.getSeconds()

      const currentTime = hour + ' : ' + minute + ' : ' + second
      
      setTime(currentTime)
    }, 1000)

  }, [])

  return <div>{time}</div>
}
```

Comment: "I have written the code using Hooks but I understand using hooks for such cases is bad for Performance" - no, it's not. There is no other up-to-date  idiomatic option in react. The idea is to not rerender a component that shouldn't be rerendered. If you need a timer, do this in a separate component, there's no need to update the whole footer

Comment: Oh Thanks for Noticing that I'm using this for a Footer, So I should make a new function component for just the clock and then it should be good I Guess

Comment: @AbhayRohit Yes, you can create another component. In that case the state change will only affect the timer component. The thing is that when you call setTime() the whole component will re-render and if you have like 5 other components in your footer then they would be re-rendered as well. You could also just memoize the other components but that comes at a price and is not always worth it.

Comment: You forgot to clean up the timer, should `return () => clearInterval(timer)` from `useEffect`. Also, I'd use `date.toLocaleTimeString()` instead of getting hours/minutes/seconds separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely good that you're thinking about performance however in this situation I wouldn't change a single thing. In order to change what gets rendered to the screen (in this case the text of the clock), the component has to be re-rendered to reflect the change in it's state, which is not such a bad thing. Each time the component re-renders it's not going to cause the parent to re-render so performance-wise we're doing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The time will only be updated once when the component initially renders, and it won't update again automatically because the useEffect hook's dependency array is empty [].

To continuously update the time every second, you should include the time state variable in the dependency array of the useEffect hook. This way, the effect will re-run whenever the time state changes, allowing the time to update every second.